# Elastic beanstalk worker is giving error with sample-application

Tags: python, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

It is giving following error:-

```
[Instance: {instance_id} Module: AWSEBAutoScalingGroup ConfigSet: null] 
Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 
Output: Error occurred during build: Command 01-start-sqsd failed
```

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Did you checked eb-tools.log file in /var/log of your EB's EC2 instance? Maybe, You can find out more details.

Comment: It is just saying, 01-start-sqsd is failed to run..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is coming because of some permission issue. After giving administrator permission it started working. [Still not the good idea to give administrator permission.]

Comment: Administrator access on your pc? In IAM? I'm having the same problem, but I'm not sure where the permission problem is.

Comment: In IAM. Try to apply Administrator policy instead of elasticbeanstalk policy.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Anurag. But asked the question here on stack and got the right answer. You can see it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304703/deploying-laravel-5-with-aws-eb-cli-unexpectedvalueexception-invalid-version) - *TEASER* my problem was in composer.lock

Answer (score 4):

You should look into logs to get better idea what has failed.

EC2 instance commands:
`/var/log/eb-tools.log`

Elastic Beanstalk container commands:
`/var/log/cfn-init.log`

If you look into logs and don't see anything to help you to amend the situation, then to SSH to the instance and execute those commands by hand. It should give you a greater flexibility. Once you get those commands working in a manual mode, move them to your configuration file and test again.

Also, you can update your question with a snippet from the configuration file, it might help to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that the ElasticBeanstalk script "01-start-sqsd" failed to run. You can probably find this script in /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/preinit though I haven't worked with worker instances yet. Do you have AWS credentials set in your environment configuration? That would be the most likely cause for that to fail.

Comment: I have given AWS credentials. But it is still failing. 

Do you know what type of access we have to have for that IAM credential. ??