# Deploying laravel 5 with AWS EB cli: UnexpectedValueException - Invalid version string

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, composer-php, laravel-5

So I was just about to deploy some changes for the first time in some months, and I get this error back:

```
  [UnexpectedValueException]                                                  
  Could not parse version constraint ^1.2.2: Invalid version string "^1.2.2"
```

After some digging, I found the line in my composer.lock file:

```
{
    "_readme": [
        ...
    ],
    "hash": "NotTellingYou",
    "packages": [
        {
         ...
        },
         ....
        "require": {
                "nikic/php-parser": "^1.2.2",
                "php": ">=5.3.3",
                "symfony/console": "~2.1",
                "symfony/filesystem": "~2.1",
                "symfony/finder": "~2.1"
            },
```

But ehhh... How do I make the string the "correct" then? I know the newest version is 1.3, but is it okay for me to change that? Shouldn't it be automatic when running `composer update`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change "nikic/php-parser": "^1.2.2"
to "nikic/php-parser": "1.*",

Comment: Worked like a charm. I manually rewrote every instance containing "^" to "x.*" in the main composer.lock and I was running again. Thanks!

Comment: This isn't the same version. The original wants to use AT LEAST version 1.2.2, and allows compatible updates. Your replacements allows EVERY version of the 1.x kind, without checking whether the 1.1 or 1.0 has all the features needed by the software. This isn't a problem now, but it will become a problem once a third package is installed that requires a lower version of the PHP parser. At least you could have used the correct replacement: `~1.2,>=1.2.2`.

Comment: Ah, okay. Will do that next time. I thought the newest version would always work backwards as long as it wasnt a major change e.g. 1.2 -> 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Update the Composer version you are using. The feature of using the `^` operator has been added in December 2014, so everyone should have gotten an updated copy of Composer by now

```
composer self-update
```

This is the key to prevent incompatibility issues. Note that Composer is still in development, and there are some alpha releases. Using it means to also update it regularly.

Comment: Ahh, I gues it means AWS is using an outdated version then. AWS runs a composer update when my app is pushed from git. If they have an old version, it makes sense they repport an error with the new syntax (or is it called semantics?) I have run composer self-update 3 times today followed by composer update, so I'm sure I'm up to date.

Comment: Just wanted to say I had forgotten to update my instance environment on AWS. After updating, it had the newest version of composer as well, and I don't have to make the changes anymore.

Comment: See [Reduce Composer Issues on Elastic Beanstalk](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php/post/Tx2M04LCN1UEE0E/Reduce-Composer-Issues-on-Elastic-Beanstalk) on the AWS PHP Development Blog for more details about the cause and solution to this issue.