# AWS elastic beanstalk git deployment suddenly failing due to composer issue despite no changes to composer.json

Tags: amazon-web-services, composer-php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a number of environments running in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I deploy direct from git using git aws.push.

I use composer.json to install required php sdk's. I've not changed this file for a long time but it's suddenly started failing in all environments.

Output from the AWS logs is

```
+ echo 'Found composer.json file. Attempting to install vendors.'
Found composer.json file. Attempting to install vendors.
+ composer.phar install --no-ansi --no-interaction
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies



  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                 
  Could not load package aws/aws-sdk-php in http://packagist.org:     [UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse version constraint ^5.3:     Invalid version string "^5.3"  






  [UnexpectedValueException]                                              
  Could not parse version constraint ^5.3: Invalid version string "^5.3"  



install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader]



2015-05-28 09:57:18,414 [ERROR] (15056 MainThread)     [directoryHooksExecutor.py-33] [root directoryHooksExecutor error] Script     /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_composer_install.sh failed     with returncode 1
```

my composer.json is:

```
{
"require": {
    "aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.7.*",
    "monolog/monolog": "1.0.*",
    "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*",
    "ext-curl": "*",
    "paypal/sdk-core-php": "v1.4.2",
    "paypal/permissions-sdk-php":"v2.5.106",
    "paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php":"2.*"
}
}
```

I notice it does want the aws-sdk-php but the version is not 5.3 (which is mentioned in the logs).

5.3 makes me think php version, checking php -v i get

```
php -v
PHP 5.5.12 (cli) (built: May 20 2014 22:27:36)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.4-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend     Technologies
```

I've tried re-installing older versions that have previously installed fine and they also fail with the same error. This has to be due to the environment. Does anyone know if there have been changes recently.

Comment: Look here
[answer here][1]

You simply need new version of composer


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30304703/deploying-laravel-5-with-aws-eb-cli-unexpectedvalueexception-invalid-version

Comment: It should be `composer self-update`, not `composer update`, because you want to update Composer itself, not the dependencies of your software.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a folder in your root of the project called .ebextensions. Then create a new file in there called 01-composer-install.config with the following content.

```
commands:
  01_update_composer:
    command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
    value: /root
```

Comment: I can't comment on the AWS side of your answer, but the intention is correct and looks reasonable.

Comment: mike - i owe you a beer. thanks it worked a treat. So this will automatically update composer each time i run a push. sweet :)

Comment: That script works great!  Note that you may need to terminate the instance after adding the script to get it to work.

Comment: @mrog interesting, that shouldn't be needed but great debugging. That wouldn't hurt to start fresh if this didn't work out of the box.

Comment: I also found that everything worked without the script if I deleted the EB app (not just the environment) and started over from scratch.  But that wasn't an option for me for one app, so I'm happily using the script.

Comment: Here is the background of the issue and summary of the solution on the AWS PHP Development Blog: http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php/post/Tx2M04LCN1UEE0E/Reduce-Composer-Issues-on-Elastic-Beanstalk

Answer (score 0):

I just had to update composer using the instructions here:
https://getcomposer.org/download/